# Python - Convert .txt file to .xls or .xlsx

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xls, txt

I have data which came in the form .data, so I have converted it to .txt files due to opening in it Microsoft Excel not fully loading it. There are over 2 million rows.

For this reason, I decided to try converted .txt to .xls or .xlsx using python with this script:

```
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = 'path/to/inputfile.txt'
output_file = 'path/to/outputfile.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)
```

but I am getting the error `for row in reader: _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

[image: txt data format]

Comment: Two million rows - won't save in an Excel file, unless you use multiple sheets. Excel is *not* suitable for this much data.

Comment: @BigBen I need to upload it into a database table on Microsoft SQL and one of the only ways to import data is via excel file. How can I resolve this?

Comment: And you really can't use a CSV file, for example?

Comment: What tool are you using to upload? I'd guess SSIS, which does parse csv/tsv files

Comment: @BigBen no it says .xls or .xlsx only

Comment: @C.Nivs SQL server import and export wizard

Comment: Is that a company/team setting? According to the docs, you should be able to import a [text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @C.Nivs I don't think so? But wouldn't be entirely sure will try and  look into it

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the correct mode in the second parameter when [opening](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file.

With `rb` you are opening it in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o), but here you should write `r` to use [text mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o).

So your code should be:

```py
import csv
import openpyxl

input_file = 'path/to/inputfile.txt'
output_file = 'path/to/outputfile.xls'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

with open(input_file, 'r') as data:  # read in text mode
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save(output_file)
```

---

As already mentioned in a comment, Excel is not suitable for this amount of data as its limited to 1048576 rows, but gets quite slow to handle even below that. You should really try to import as csv or directly as tsv.